# Thread Method Outrunning ProgressChanged

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a simple application that executes a function in a separate thread via a BackgroundWorker and am running into issues.  I am collecting a string array of values and passing that back to my ProgressChanged event via the ReportProgress method and I'm running into a problem where the thread continues and is so fast, it outruns the ProgressChanged event and overwrites the values before they can be added to a grid.  Below is my code...

Button Click Event Fires my thread...

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkingPathTextBox.Text))
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
        this.LoadButton.Visible = false;
        this.BrowseButton.Enabled = false;
        this.WorkingPathTextBox.Enabled = false;
        this.CancelBtn.Visible = true;
        this.ProcessingLabel.Visible = true;

        beginTime = DateTime.Now;

        WorkflowCleanup wc = new WorkflowCleanup();
        wc.WorkflowPath = this.WorkingPathTextBox.Text; 
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(wc);
    }
}
```

In the DoWork, it loads the class where my work exists...

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker;
    worker = (System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)sender;

    // Get the Words object and call the main method.
    WorkflowCleanup wc = (WorkflowCleanup)e.Argument;
    wc.LoadAssemblies(worker, e);
    wc.LoadDataDefinitions(worker, e);
    wc.LoadDataDefinitionsDirty(worker, e);
    wc.LoadProcesses(worker, e);
    wc.LoadProcessesDirty(worker, e);
    wc.LoadWorkflows(worker, e);

    // wc.UpdateWorkflows(worker, e);
}
```

WorkflowCleanup class...the ReportProgress in stuck right in the middle of the try/catch because I could not figure out what was causing the problem.  So, I moved it in the try, and even had to add a Thread.Sleep(100) to slow the process down to give the ProgressChanged event time enough to add the row of data I passed it to the grid before it was overridden...

```
namespace WorkflowMaintenance
{
    public class WorkflowCleanup
    {
        private int errorCount = 0;
        private int fixCount = 0;

        public class Workflow 
        { 
            // code truncated
        }
        public class WorkflowAssembly 
        {
            // code truncated
        }

        public class DataDefinition
        {
            // code truncated
        }

        public class CurrentState
        {
            public int Percentage;
            public string StateString;
            public List<string[]> ProcessResults;
            public string[] Result;
            public int ErrorCount;
            public int FixCount;
        }

        public void LoadAssemblies(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentState state = new CurrentState();
            fixCount = 0;
            errorCount = 0;

            string[] asmbfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(WorkflowPath + "\\Assemblies", "*.asmb", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            int asmbIndex = 0;

            Assemblies = new List<WorkflowAssembly>();

            // Assemblies (NEW)
            foreach (string asmb in asmbfiles)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //results = new List<string[]>();

                    asmbIndex += 1;
                    int percentage = (asmbIndex * 100) / asmbfiles.Length;
                    state.StateString = string.Format("Loading Assemblies... {0}%", percentage);
                    state.Percentage = percentage;

                    try
                    {
                        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(asmb);
                        XElement asmbElement = xdoc.Descendants(wf + "assembly").First();
                        XElement asmbTypes = asmbElement.Element(wf + "types");
                        string asmbid = asmbElement.Attribute("id").Value;
                        string asmbname = asmbElement.Element(wf + "name").Value;
                        string asmbpath = asmbElement.Element(wf + "assemblyPath").Value;

                        Assemblies.Add(new WorkflowAssembly() { ID = asmbid, Name = asmbname, FileName = asmb, AssemblyPath = asmbpath, Types = asmbTypes });
                        //results.Add(new string[] { "SUCCESS", "ASSEMBLY PROCESSED SUCCESSFULLY", asmbname, asmbid, null, asmb });
                        state.Result = new string[] { "SUCCESS", "ASSEMBLY PROCESSED SUCCESSFULLY", asmbname, asmbid, null, asmb };
                        fixCount += 1;

                        //if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
                        //{
                        //    state.ProcessResult = results;
                        //}

                        state.FixCount = fixCount;
                        state.ErrorCount = errorCount;

                        worker.ReportProgress(percentage, state);
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // need to report the exception...
                        errorCount += 1;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        //if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
                        //{
                        //    state.ProcessResult = results;
                        //}

                        //state.FixCount = fixCount;
                        //state.ErrorCount = errorCount;

                        //worker.ReportProgress(percentage, state);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

ProgressChanged Event...

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // This method runs on the main thread.
    WorkflowCleanup.CurrentState state = (WorkflowCleanup.CurrentState)e.UserState;

    this.progressBar1.Value = state.Percentage;
    this.ProcessingLabel.Text = state.StateString;
    this.errorLabel.Text = string.Format("Errors: {0}", state.ErrorCount);
    this.fixLabel.Text = string.Format("Fixed: {0}", state.FixCount);

    this.ElapsedTimeLabel.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time: {0}", GetProgressElapsedString());

    if (state.Result != null)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(state.Result);
    }
}
```

Problem...the problem is that if I have 3 files in the folder (named Assembly1, Assembly2, and Assembly3), the output in the grid shows that all three are named Assembly3.  The only way I could fix this was to tell the Thread to sleep.  This is not an option as I have to run this for a folder that has approximately 18,000 files and having to sleep for a millisecond would take forever.  BUT, I need to get valid results.  Help please :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating the `state` object outside the loop and mutating it in each iteration, create a new instance for each iteration.  This can be done by simply moving the declaration of the variable inside the loop.

Comment: I was about to update my question.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I knew if I had a second set of eyes, something would pop out.  Yeah, I now declare it in the same place, but create it inside my else statement.

Comment: @Keith Why?  There is no reason for this to exist outside of the loop at all.  You should always scope every single variable at the smallest possible scope that allows it to still function properly.  In this case that means declaring the variable inside that `else`.